# Cucumber-JVM Runner class in different folder

Tags: java, junit, bdd, cucumber-jvm, gherkin

I am new to Cucumber and learning and trying to automate application. I created a new Test Project. I want to keep the feature files and Cucumber runner class in a different folder and all the glue code in another  folder.

How do I specify the feature file path under @CucumberOptions?

The project folder structure is as follows:

```
Project-2
|-src
  |-test
    |-java
      |-mypackage
        |-CucucmberRunner.java
|-resources
      |-MyFeature.feature

Project-1
|-src
  |-test
    |-java
      |-mypackage
        |-MyFeatureTest.java
```

I tried giving "@CucumberOptions(features = "Project-2/resources/MyFeature.feature" ) but it is throwing `NoSuchMethodError`.

Can somebody please help!!

Comment: Provide details of for which method you are getting the error and are you using maven or gradle or anything else for dependency management?

Comment: Can anybody help me in resolving this issue on cucumber-jvm

Answer (score 0):

Add Project-1 dependency on Project-2 i.e. at runtime the test classes of Project-1 should be available in the classpath when you execute the cucumber tests.

Check `mvn dependency:tree` output and look for cucumber dependencies. All the dependencies are of same version i.e. cucumber-core, cucumber-junit, etc.

Comment: Iam using maven and pom.xml has got only jar dependencies , i hve added project dependency under java build path , but of no use it is throwing error as below   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptionsFactory.<init>(Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Class;)V
 at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:59)

Comment: Thanks Bhushan, also i noticed that feature is not recognising the gluecode ,below the story line & implementation                                        Given Iam logged in with username password
@Given("^Iam logged in with username password$")

Comment: I don't think your test classes of Project 1 are in classpath. Hence you getting this error. Please provide information how you have defined dependency of project 1 in project 2.

Comment: Bushan i have attached the screenshot in the answer section

Answer (score 0):

Bhushan Please click the link for  [Project Folders Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0j9mN.jpg)